# redirecting those urls which are not having any referrer urls

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, redirect

I have to redirect from www.example.com to xyz.example.com only when Header doesn't contain any referrer. I have wrote this code:

```js
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
  function(details) {
    var match = details.url.match(/^(http|https):\/\/www.example.com\/([\S\s]*)/);
    console.log(details);
    return {redirectUrl: match[1] + "://xyz.example.com/" + match[2]};
  },
  {urls: ["*://www.example.com/*"]},
  ["responseHeaders", "blocking"]
);
```

But "onHeadersReceived" doesn't contain any referrer information. So I can not write my logic further based on referrer information. There is one API "onBeforeSendHeaders" which contain referrer information But it's not able to redirect. Can you suggest any solution which can give referrer information and redirect as well. Here is the link of all API's available : [Chrome API's link](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#implementation)

Comment: Those are _response_ hearers, and Referrer is a _request_ header.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like you can only get that at `onBeforeSendHeaders` but by then it's too late to redirect the request with `webRequest`.

Comment: yes, I know, that will be requestHeader in case of "onBeforeSendHeaders", But it's not able to redirect. "How to redirect" is the question

Comment: @Xan You can redirect at `onHeadersReceived`. I [added](https://codereview.chromium.org/154473002) that feature to Chromium ;)

Comment: @RobW Then, to you the honours of answering! And to me, the shame of missing that line in the docs. The term "redirect" is slightly stretched there though: the server already received the request, it's too late to "back out" if it was, say, RESTful API.

Comment: @RobW But "onHeadersReceived" doesn't have referrer information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As RobW helpfully pointed out, it's possible to redirect a request at the `onHeadersReceived` stage.

So, the plan:

1. Identify which request you want to redirect at `onBeforeSendHeaders` stage.
2. Save the request ID.
3. Listen to `onHeadersReceived` event.
4. Compare the request ID to the saved ones.
5. Redirect if needed.

So:

```
var requestsToRedirect = new Object();

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
  function(details) {
    for (var i = 0; i < details.requestHeaders.length; i++) {
      if (details.requestHeaders[i].name === 'Referer') {
        requestsToRedirect[details.requestId] = true;
        return;
      }
    }
  },
  {urls: ["*://www.example.com/*"]},
  ["requestHeaders"]
);

chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
  function(details) {
    if(requestsToRedirect[details.requestId]) {
      delete requestsToRedirect[details.requestId];
      var match = details.url.match(/^(http|https):\/\/www.example.com\/(.*)/);
      return {redirectUrl: match[1] + "://xyz.example.com/" + match[2]};
    }
  },
  {urls: ["*://www.example.com/*"]},
  ["blocking"]
);

chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred.addListener(
  function(details) {
    // Cleanup in case we don't reach onHeadersReceived
    delete requestsToRedirect[details.requestId];
  },
  {urls: ["*://www.example.com/*"]}
);
```

Comment: just  a correction it should be ["responseHeaders", "blocking"] instead of ["blocking"]
Thank a lot :) It's perfectly working now!

Comment: @sumitkumar I don't think you need response headers: you're not looking at any of them.

Comment: 1. `blocking` at `onBeforeSendHeaders` is not needed, since you're not modifying the request 2. Move `delete` outside the `if` block, and also add the `delete` logic to `chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred`, otherwise you may end up with some obsolete entries.

Comment: @RobW If I'm not blocking, the ID might not get saved before blocking `onHeadersReceived` occurs. Moving out of `if` makes no sense as far as I can see. `onErrorOccurred` is a fair observation, I'll add that.

Comment: @Xan JavaScript is single-threaded. When the `onBeforeSendHeaders` event is dispatched, it will always complete before the callback of `onHeadersReceived` event is called. Therefore blocking the request is not needed.

Comment: Fair enough. I was just paranoid that it might interrupt the normal execution like a hardware interrupt would on a blocking request.